# Is JXTA project still alive ? "jxta.org" seems to be down?

Tags: p2p, jxta

Is JXTA project still active ? I am looking for a good Open Source Peer to peer solution, found JXTA articles, but "jxta.org" is not working,  Is it still alive ? or got it moved to some where else ?

Comment: @JVerstry : (hopefully this will notify you :-) What's the latest on JXTA/Apache Chaupal?

Comment: No news from Oracle... I have released 2.7 final today... I am quitting the leadership of the project to lead the Chaupal project (see Google projects for more info)

Answer (score 4):

Have you been to http://jxta.kenai.com/ ? This seems to be the official site for now at least.

Even though many of the links found for JXTA on Google etc seem to be dead, development seems to be moving along with a new release of 2.7 recently.

One of the most active people on JXTA appears to be  Jérôme Verstrynge (project lead maybe?) who has an account here on SO: [JVerstry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520957/jverstry) Hopefully he will come and give us more details!

He released a book as updated book on JXTA last year which I am [about to buy from Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-JXTA-II-J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-Verstrynge/dp/1446139565).
You can take a look at it on Scribd if you can bear to read it in that format ;-)
http://www.scribd.com/doc/47538921/Practical-JXTA-II

Take a look at http://java.net/projects/jxta/ and drill down for mailing list archives, forums and access details for the SVN repos for the various sub-projects

I think a lot of the reason things seem to be in limbo is that there is a proposal to move the project to be hosted as an 'incubator' project under Apache Software Foundation but Oracle are not allowing the guys to take the name JXTA with them (and so the new name Chaupal) and are currently remaining tight lipped over whether they will allow the project to be relicensed under the newer Apache license.

See here for more details: http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/ChaupalProposal

Personally I really hope the Apache move goes ahead, the project is is becoming more and more relevant in this day and age of walled garden platforms and centralised web services IMHO.

---

Edit: According to JVerstry the project hosting is moving to http://code.google.com/p/chaupal/ as we speak :-)

Comment: All the above is correct. http://jxta.kenai.com/ is the starting point on the web for latest JXTA. If JXTA does not move to Apache, Google Project Chaupal will somewhere down the road...

Comment: JXTA website:
https://jxta.kenai.com/ you can download jxta-jxsa Code:
https://svn.java.net/svn/jxta-jxse~svn/

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to get JXTA alive again:

see http://www.dzone.com/links/jxse_and_equinox_tutorial_part_1.html

Answer (score 0):

Development for the jxta 2.8x release has been moved to the [Chaupal Project](https://github.com/chaupal). Currently a few bugfixes and a move to Spongycastle has been prepared. We hope to make a milestone release available soon.